# Terraform Error 'the number of path segments is not divisible by 2' creating Azure Configuration Keys

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-configuration

I'm trying to create an Azure App Configuration service and keys through Terraform, but when I run my Terraform through my pipeline I get an error running `terraform plan`. This is my tf script for creating the service and keys:

```
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconf" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags
  sku                 = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "MainAPI" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
  key                    = "MainAPI"
  value                  = var.picking_api_url
  type                   = "kv"
  label                  = var.environment_name
}
# other keys omitted
```

This is the error I see:
`Error: while parsing resource ID: while parsing resource ID: the number of path segments is not divisible by 2 in "subscriptions/[SubscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[rgName]/providers/Microsoft.AppConfiguration/configurationStores/[AppConfigServiceName]/AppConfigurationKey/MainAPI/Label"`

I get this error regardless of whether I explicitly include a `label` argument for the key in my TF script. I've bumped up my version of the Terraform ARM provider to 2.90 in case it was a bug in the provider, but still get the error.

Comment: Could you also try the latest version of the AzureRM provider?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I've spent the afternoon trying various versions of the provider, I'm now on 3.6.0 (which according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/provider-version-history-azurerm is the latest released version) and I still get the same issue :-(

Comment: According to the official documentation, the latest version is 3.12.0. You could specify provider versions semantically (generally best practices anyway) to ensure this also.

Answer (score 0):

resource `"azurerm_app_configuration_key"` depends on `azurerm_role_assignment`. You need to define a resource for that as well for assigning role to `app_configuration`.

The following code from [the Hashicorp Terraform documentation for `azurerm_app_configuration_key`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_configuration_key) demonstrates how to do this:

> ```
> resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "appconf_dataowner" {
>   scope                = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
>   role_definition_name = "App Configuration Data Owner"
>   principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
> }
>
> resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "test" {
>   configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
>   key                    = "appConfKey1"
>   label                  = "somelabel"
>   value                  = "a test"
>
>   depends_on = [
>     azurerm_role_assignment.appconf_dataowner
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Copied without proper attribution from [the linked page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_configuration_key)

Comment: Hello @RyanM, I have shared the same document in my answer.

Comment: A link with absolutely no indication that the material is copied from it is *not* proper attribution. When quoting text from elsewhere, you must make it clear (using [quote formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)) which parts of your answer are quoted, and from where. Just putting a link to the original source somewhere in the post does **not** count as attribution. Doing so is still implicitly passing off the content as original by not clearly indicating that it's from elsewhere. Please read [this answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321326) for more information.

Comment: Acknowledge @RyanM, Will change in my answer accordingly.

Comment: This edit _does not fix the problem_.  You must make it clear *which parts of your answer* are copied.  "if you want to know more in detail about this kindly refer to" makes it sound like you wrote the code and this link just has more information.  You did not write the code.  It is from the link.  I'll edit your answer to demonstrate the correct way to do this.